# HTMLCollection will log to console, but logging .count returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

What's the deal?

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('code-block');
```

Just grabbing all my textareas.

```
console.log(blocks);
```

returns a HTMLCollection with all 14 items.

```
console.log(blocks.count);
```

returns

```
undefined
```

I did try setTimeout but that didn't help. I'm also inside a document.ready function and in the global scope.
If it makes a difference, all my textareas are inside of a .collapsible div from Materialize.css so they are not initially visible.

Comment: Did you mean `length`?!

Comment: oh man my Swift brain has completely taken over. hahaha thanks man..

Answer (score 0):

```
blocks.length
```

is the answer wow I've been working with Swift way too much lately I guess haha.